# Bris Milah vs Bris Periah and Deuteronomy 4

Tags: brit-milah, deuteronomy

Full disclosure I am not Jewish. This is (it sadly needs to be said) not meant to be anti-Semitic in any way, shape or form, but it's an honest question. I am not that familiar with the Talmud or oral law but I am pretty familiar with the Hebrew bible and am learning more every day.

In Deuteronomy 4:1-2, in the English Standard Version, it is written:

> And now, O Israel, listen to the statutes and the rules that I am
> teaching you, and do them, that you may live, and go in and take
> possession of the land that the LORD, the God of your fathers, is
> giving you.  You shall not add to the word that I command you, nor
> take from it, that you may keep the commandments of the LORD your God
> that I command you.

I think the difference between Bris Milah and Bris Periah is commonly understood in Judaism and the view that Periah was added centuries later - not until the age of the Greeks and Romans- is not challenged. If I'm wrong, feel free to discuss, but consider consider Exodus 4:25 "Then Zipporah took a flint and cut off her son’s foreskin" ( i.e. just like that)

I'm wondering [in an 'ask a Rabbi' fashion or something], learning as I have about the difference between Bris Milah Versus Bris Periah, how does Deuteronomy 4 and the prohibition against adding to the commands of God not apply here? It seems like a substantial addition to a commandment.

That's my sole question and I don't want us to venture outside the narrow scope of the above, but if you're curious about my interest as a non-Jew, I consider myself to (very personally and inseverably) have skin in the game, precisely because I no longer have 'skin' in the game, otherwise I probably wouldn't even know what these things are.

Thank you, Shalom and Simcha

**Edit**: It seems that people use Joshua 5:2 as evidence that Periah was always a thing because of the command to circumcise the Israelites again before entering the promised land. I do not believe a plain reading of the text justifies this, if you read through to verse 8.

> *4Now this is why he did so*: All those who came out of Egypt—all the
> men of military age—died in the wilderness on the way after leaving
> Egypt. 5All the people that came out had been circumcised, but *all the
> people born in the wilderness during the journey from Egypt had not*.
> 6The Israelites had moved about in the wilderness forty years until
> all the men who were of military age when they left Egypt had died,
> since they had not obeyed the Lord. For the Lord had sworn to them
> that they would not see the land he had solemnly promised their
> ancestors to give us, a land flowing with milk and honey. 7So he
> raised up their sons in their place, and *these were the ones Joshua
> circumcised. They were still uncircumcised because they had not been
> circumcised on the way* (NIV)

I don't mean to be controversial but I don't know how it could be written more plainly in my translation.

Comment: http://www.mohelinsouthflorida.com/2018/04/periah.html https://etzion.org.il/en/halakha/yoreh-deah/circumcision/stages-brit-mila-2-peria

Comment: I read these links. I added an edit above re: Joshua 5, but basically other than that, it seems like all the evidence in favor is from the Talmud and just tradition, and may be contra-indicated by the Zipporah account.

Comment: Saying that something is from the Talmud does not, according to Judaism, make it any less essential or authoritative. The Talmud presents scriptural supports so this practice is more than "tradition" - it is a commandment based in scripture.

Comment: "_I think the difference between Bris Milah and Bris Periah is commonly understood in Judaism..._" what makes you think that? I hadn't heard of 'Bris Periah', until reading this question, and Google searches (of ["bris periah"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bris+periah%22), ["brit periah"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22brit+periah%22), or ["ברית פריעה"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%94%22)), don't seem turn up any _Jewish legal_ sources using the term.

Comment: "_I think_ ... _the view that Periah was added centuries later - not until the age of the Greeks and Romans- is not challenged._" Not challenged by who? [Wikipedia on Brit Milah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brit_milah#cite_ref-55) says: "According to Rabbinic interpretation of traditional Jewish sources, the 'priah' has been performed as part of the Jewish circumcision since the Israelites first inhabited the Land of Israel."

Comment: @rosends Yes, I concede your point. I should have been more clear in my language or have asked my question differently- is there any non-Talmudic evidence that supports your faith in Periah (like in Tanakh) - because the Talmud is a point of faith to most practicing Jews (virtually all non-Karaites) and has to be taken as a given. I'm guessing that's the main thing this question comes down to - one's view on the Talmud, which 99% of practicing Jews believe on, according to my understanding. If there's nothing else to add, then thank you for your comments.

Comment: @TamirEvan . I concede I was pretty sloppy in my writing but my intention was good. I'm guessing that while Jews know more about circumcision than most others (it's their rite first and foremost) the average Jewish person may also know less of it or certain aspects of it and its history than those (Jews and Gentiles) who have questioned the practice or studied restoration. I should have said "as commonly understood, where understood", or not by the individual but by the group. I was still wrong there, but they (Mohels, sages) have definitely heard of the two, as they named and wrote of them!

Comment: @TamirEvan Secondly, I was wrong that it's commonly understood in Judiasm. 
About that, I do remember reading a source that said the Jewish Encyclopedia of 1908 said Periah was added later, but I didn't check and it's quote mining. Sorry. 

I think most non-Jewish sources are strongly of the opinion that it was added later, but I glossed over the rabbinic interpretation part of Wikipedia, as it didn't interest me at the time. I did use Wikipedia and Google and articles as my main indicator of 'common knowledge'...

Comment: @TamirEvan ..From my view, it seems like the Rabbinic interpretation is the island or outlier, and that's fine, but I think that is the case, and also how could restoration (epispasm) happen as mentioned in Maccabees 1:14-15, if Periah? How could the pondus Judaeus be a thing if Periah? I know the Talmud says Periah was from the beginning, and that it's your scripture but is there anything else that says so? As a non Talmudist, I respect it as a matter of your faith but I'm myself not sold. Respectfully.

Comment: @agman I looked at a couple of Maccabees texts. One, in English says "they disguised their circumcisions." Another has "they made foreskins for themselves." Then I looked for a Hebrew text and it reads (via sefaria.org) ולא מלו עוד את בניהם they no longer circumcised their sons. I am not sure what the "original" text is and how it relates to your understanding. [I recall a scene from Europa, Europa in which a Jewish man works to sew his skin back to cover the circumcision -- clearly he did so after a modern 2-step procedure]

Comment: @rosends 1 Maccabees only survives in Greek (per wikipedia), so any Hebrew is a new translation. I happen to have an LXX interlinear. In the Greek it says ἀκροβυστίας (Strong's 203: prepuce, foreskin, hence uncircumcision). Actual circumcision in Greek is an unrelated word: περιτομή

How I understand they restored then is like today, they had devices to stretch existing skin (pondus Judaeus), which (I argue) was more extant at the time. Even non Jewish Greeks tied string around in competition, much like 'retaining' today only difference being what they had to work with.

Comment: Regardless, I will be studying more to increase my understanding as there is plenty of material online and I prefer facts over opinions, even my own. It is good to be challenged. Iron sharpens iron. If one is not completely committed to the Talmud as divine source of revelation, then there are grounds for considering that maybe the two forms are not identical and I'll leave the individual to ponder what that allows.